# Where is Bitcoin information (wallet.dat) stored on OS X?

Tags: mac

Is there a wallet.dat for OSX? Where is it located?

Taken from https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/544

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The Bitcoin wallet on Mac OS X is located in `~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/wallet.dat`.

---

[Mac OS X v10.7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Lion) (Lion) came out, and it has the `~/Library` folder hidden, see the [answer from chilled35](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/5293/108) to access it with Finder.

> In order to see hidden folders, such as `~/Library` from Finder, simply hit `shift + ⌘ (command) + G` which will GO to a folder, then paste in this location:
>
> ```
> ~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin
> ```
>
> From there, you will see all the files associated with your wallet.

Comment: hmm I can't find this in Mountain Lion...

Comment: hmm, I discovered I can see it in terminal, but not in Finder.

Comment: Remember, this is the *default* location. If you installed Bitcoin a long time ago, you may have chosen another folder somewhere else... For example, mine was in `~/Documents/Bitcoin`

Answer (score 7):

In order to see hidden folders, such as `~/Library` from Finder, simply hit `shift + ⌘ (command) + G` which will GO to a folder, then paste in this location:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin
```

From there, you will see all the files associated with your wallet.

Having moved all my BTC to another location, I recovered more than 5 GB of storage space by deleting my local wallet.