# OS X 10.7 - Where is Bitcoin data stored?

Tags: wallet, mac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there wallet.dat for OSX?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1350/is-there-wallet-dat-for-osx)

Upgrading my HD; clean install and I want to copy the wallett etc from old hard drive. What do I need to copy? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin data on Mac OS X located in ~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/ . Just copy the whole folder to the new HDD to use your old wallet and downloaded blockchain with the new copy of Bitcoin client.