# Unable to find a directory where to put wallet.dat file from my old wallet when I am on my Mac

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet.dat, mac

I am on macOS 12 on (MacBook Air M1) with the latest updates applied.

I have installed Bitcoin Core from the bitcoin org website and currently it is downloading the whole blockchain and it will for a few days according to the sync pop up.

The problem is that I have an old wallet.dat file but I don't know where to copy it so I can select it from the menu of the Qt Bitcoin-Core app when selecting `File > Open Wallet`. Currently I see only my test-wallet I have created jsut so there is something while the app is downloading the blockchain.

Google search suggested to go to `Library > Application Support > Bitcoin` but the problem is that I don't see any Bitcoin folder there. I have tried to clean up by name in that folder but nothing has changed. Here is my screenshot:

[image]

Any idea how can I tell Bitcoin Core app to use my old wallet.dat file on my MacBook Air?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is Bitcoin information (wallet.dat) stored on OS X?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1350/where-is-bitcoin-information-wallet-dat-stored-on-os-x)  -- note the mention of a *hidden* folder.

Comment: No,, could it be that I have it downloading to my exterrnal harddisk? Because I see a test-wallet folder that contains wallet.dat file there. Should I create e.g. "old-wallet" folder on the same folder level as "test-wallet" and upload my old wallet.dat file there? By the way where I can find some guide how to do these importing of old wallet.dat file without reading some blog posts full of adds? Is there a wikipage for that? Also should I cope cahinstate, database, db.log, debug.log peers.dat wallet.dat from my old folder or just wallet.dat?

Comment: I would download Bitcoin core from https://bitcoincore.org/en/download/ not from bitcoin.org. I would follow the instructions at https://bitcoincore.org/en/download/ for verifying the software. I can't comment on your other questions.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick thanks, :D seems like Bitcoin domain-parasite things is even a bigger anarchy in 2022 than in 2014. How can normies use it is beyond my understanding. It's so difficult. In 2014 I was told it will improve, but it the opposite. It's deception and fog on every BTC google search.